# Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0) in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse string date to date , but getting error of java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0).Here is method for converting date.Exception occur at this line   **Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);**

```
public static String convertDateStringFormat(String dateString, String originalDateFormat, String outputDateFormat){
            String finalDate = null;
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(originalDateFormat);
            try {
                Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
                simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat);
                finalDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return finalDate;
        }



String newDateString = Constant.convertDateStringFormat(strActiondate , "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
Log.e("newDateString ","  = " + newDateString );
```

Some string dates are converted , some date are getting null and occur java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0) .

Here is my log cat error

```
02-22 10:40:15.539  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/newDateString﹕ = null
02-22 10:40:15.539  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/newDateString﹕ = 2015-12-03 12:00:00 AM
02-22 10:40:15.540  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/newDateString﹕ = 2015-12-09 12:00:00 AM
02-22 10:40:15.540  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/newDateString﹕ = 2015-12-01 12:00:00 AM
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.AdapterClasses.Constant.convertDateStringFormat(Constant.java:49)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.CustomActionActivity.GetAllActivityList(CustomActionActivity.java:1572)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.CustomActionActivity$GetAllServicesDetails.doInBackground(CustomActionActivity.java:1229)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.CustomActionActivity$GetAllServicesDetails.doInBackground(CustomActionActivity.java:1216)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 10:40:15.541  11336-11465/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of the date you want to parse ?

Comment: you're trying to parse an empty string as a date. like String date=""

Answer (score 2):

The format of the exception is normally

```
java.text.ParseException: 
    Unparseable date: "Mon Oct 20 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2014" (at offset 0)
```

...with the unparsable date a part of the exception message, and you're getting...

```
java.text.ParseException: 
    Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)
```

...which means you're *trying to parse an empty string as a date*.

Comment: I'm trying to chack the null on String date since getting same error.if(strActiondate != null)
                    {
                        newDateString = Constant.convertDateStringFormat(strActiondate , "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
                        Log.e("newDateString ","  = " + newDateString );
                    }